# How to add anything at a specific position in a string using vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript

For Example need to add a slash `/` in between `USDYEN` so it need to output `USD/YEN`.

Answer (score 2):

1. One way is to FIND and replace `USD` for `USD/` then it will output `USD/YEN`
2. However, how about if `USD` is not found because it's another currency let's say `EUR/YEN`?

The trick here is to slice or cut the `string` at a particular position for example at the third character then add a slash `/` then add the same string but without the first 3 characters.

```js
var str = 'USDYEN'
// add a / in between currencies

// var newStr = str.slice(3) // removes the first 3 chars
// var newStr = str.slice(0,3) // removes the last 3 chars

var newStr = str.slice(0,3) + ' / ' + str.slice(3) // removes the first 3 and adds the last 3

console.log(newStr)
```

Here the string is being removed

More info into how to use `slice()` 
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_string.asp

Answer (score 1):

```js
const pair = Array.from('USDGBP')
pair.splice(3, 0, '/')
console.log(pair.join(''))
```